# ASK SDK V2 - .addAudioPlayDirective - no metadata

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

the Audio Player works fine. The mp3 file is playing well.

But the metadata doesn´t works.

I changed the code thousand times, but I don´t find the issue. :-)

My echo show don´t show title, subtitle or the art.

Can anybody help me please?

Thanks.

```js
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                            .speak("Hello")
                            .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective('REPLACE_ALL',  "https://my-url/audiofile.mp3",   Math.random().toString(), 0, null, undefined, {
                              title: "Article",
                              subtitle: "Subtitel",
                              art: {
                                sources: [
                                  {
                                    url: "https://my-url/art.png"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              backgroundImage: {
                                sources: [
                                  {
                                    url: "https://my-url/bg.png"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            })
                            .getResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding an extra parameter as `undefined` to `addAudioPlayerPlayDirective` unnecessarily. But however, the below one worked for me please try that.

```
.addAudioPlayerPlayDirective(
         "Your play behavior goes here like ENQUEUE/REPLACE_ALL", 
         "Your audio URL",
         "Current Token ID",
         "offset",
         "Previous Token ID",
         AudioItemMetadata )
```

AudioItemMetadata is an object which consists of

```
let AudioItemMetadata = {}
AudioItemMetadata.title = "Your audio title";
var audioimageEnclousre = {
                    "sources": [
                        {
                            "url": "Your current audio image"
                        }
                    ]
                };

var backgroundimageEnclousure = {
                    "sources": [
                        {
                            "url": "Your background image"
                        }
                    ]
                };

AudioItemMetadata.art = audioimageEnclousre;
AudioItemMetadata.backgroundImage = backgroundimageEnclousure;
```

Hope this works..

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed the addAudioPlayerPlayDirective and delete the undefined statement. What I don´t understand is, how can I add the AudioItemMetadata? I can´t use it in my code. Is a declaration (const or let) necessary?

Comment: Updated the code, Please check and upvote it, if that helped you.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. I tried your code. There is no error message and the audio works fine. But, there is not title, subtitle or my custom image. I don´t know what my error is. :-( I tried it 1000 times.

Comment: Can you send me the JSON response of your skill when requested for audio?